# Pre-flight request takes more time (275% more) than normal request

Tags: node.js, angular6, preflight, http-options-method

**Overview**

> I'm using **Angular 6** as a front end for an web application which will communicate with the REST API developed in **NodeJs**. I've an Issue that the Preflight request takes long time than the normal request.

**Detail**

> My frontend **Angular 6** application communicates with the REST API to get data from the Database and display it to the user. I'm sending the request via **HttpClient** to the REST API.
>
> In my REST API developed in **NodeJs** all CORS configurations are done correctly and the preflight request are successfully sent and the actual request are processed perfectly in local development machine.
>
> The issue what I've is that, when I deploy the application in the production machine the options (preflight) request takes more time than the actual GET / POST request (See Image attached). As you can see the Actual **GET** request takes only **239ms** while the **preflight (OPTIONS)** request takes **656ms**, which is almost **275%** more than normal. This happens in all HTTP request which in turn affects my website performance.

[image]

Comment: It could be that the first request to your backend is slow because it is waiting to open a HTTP connection. Can you see what the timing breakdown for the request is?

Comment: It is for all preflight request not only for the first request